# Safer alternative to using .smbcredentials

Tags: permissions, mount, password, samba, security

At work we are using a server for our working group where we all have our own accounts. We also have storage from the institution that our group is part of. So everyone's storage is mounted in the `/etc/fstab` file, e.g.

```
//external/storage /mounting/point cifs noperm,cred=/home/user/.smbcredentials,domain=WORK,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2i,uid=user,gid=WORKGROUP,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770 0 0
```

and everyone put their credentials in their `/home/user/.smbcredentials` file, e.g.

```
user=user
password=pass
```

However, this file is in plain text. The permissions are correct so only the user can view/change the file, but so can `sudo` AFAIK. The issue is that the password is *also* the password to sensitive information of the user as part of the institution (so the storage is linked to the same account as the sensitive information). My fear is, then, that if the server or even just the user's account is compromised, this may have grave consequences because the passwords are available right there in plain text.

My question then is: how can this be made more secure? Surely there must be an alternative to plaintext passwords?

Comment: If you don't trust your admins who have `sudo` then you shouldn't be giving `sudo` out.  Rule #1 of Linux Security: don't give out `sudo` unless you trust the person to not have access to the system in ways that could be 'insecure'

Comment: @ThomasWard would still be an extra layer of security in case the system is hacked. It is not anymore of today to store passwords unencrypted on a hard drive. Up to today, it does not seem that smbclient supports storing a password differently than in plain text.

Comment: Currently, `smbclient` which handles the CIFS handoff requires access to the plaintext credentials.  Check the manpage for `smbclient` and see the -U and -A arguments items - that is the only way to pass creds in currently - plaintext

Comment: @vanadium true, but if your server is hacked you have another problem, not just 'plaintext credentials' - that's when you lock out accounts, etc. and force password changes.  (Either way, you should still *not* give `sudo` out :P)

Comment: Why not use different passwords for samba?  That's not one people seem to need to remember a lot.

Comment: @ThomasWard I am aware of that. But even if sudo is not hacked; and just one person's account - their account credentials for the storage can then also be used for other things within the institution. So even if control over the server is not lost but only one user is compromised on that machine, this could lead to further problems. The only way to prevent this (to me) is with encryption, but it seems then that samba does not allow that.

Comment: @OrganicMarble As written, this is out of our hands. The passwords required by the institution are one for everything (admin, mail, storage). This is not ideal, of course, but neither is storing those passwords in plaintext. But if that is the only option, perhaps I suggest that they allow (or better, require) different passwords for samba/storage access.

Comment: That's what I do on our (tiny) system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for encrypted credentials.  From the `smbclient` manpage regarding `-U` and `-A` which is what is passed behind the scenes:

```
   -A|--authentication-file=filename
       This option allows you to specify a file from which to read the
       username and password used in the connection.
       ...
       Make certain that the permissions on the file restrict access from
       unwanted users.

   -U|--user=username[%password]
       Sets the SMB username or username and password.

       ...
       A third option is to use a credentials file which contains the
       plaintext of the username and password. This option is mainly
       provided for scripts where the admin does not wish to pass the
       credentials on the command line or via environment variables. If
       this method is used, make certain that the permissions on the file
       restrict access from unwanted users. See the -A for more details.
       ...
```

This is current even in 20.04 currently.  You must use plain-text credentials.

---

You state the 'risk of a user's account being breached' is a risk, and these credentials are also admin creds:

> The passwords required by the institution are one for everything (admin, mail, storage).

Rule #2 of IT Security is the concept of **least privilege and privilege separation**.  This is where you separate admin and non-admin accounts.  **All good organizations have some aspect of this in play** and this then prevents 'admin' access on other systems.  Storage and Email access is simply a matter of having to audit access attempts or restrict how someone can access information.

The other problem though is, if your system is hacked, you have a host of other problems *the least of which* is password leakage for one specific user (which you could fix with a forced password change in your Active Directory / LDAP system).

The only other way to do this *without* password leakage might be to write a wrapper around the mounting, request credentials manually, and then execute a mount command directly without exposing the credentials file or the password.  The tricky part here is, this has to be manually user-entered and executed, which means your automatic fstab mount won't work.  It also would require specialized access (or a specific `sudoers` entry to work right) because you'd be passing the mount options in and only `root` can do that currently in all `mount` setups.

And as for the rest of your comment:

> ... perhaps I suggest that they allow (or better, require) different passwords for samba/storage access

... you'd have to take that up with the Samba developers [on samba.org](https://www.samba.org/).  Chances are though this is a request already somewhere in line, but Windows interoperability is a pain so...

Comment: I understand your conclusion, and I'll have peace with that this is not possible. However, I still think this is a special case and not just "standard for any organization". Put simply: if a user is hacked and their password to the local machine is retrieved, the hackers also have access to the plaintext password to the institution's services and server. I.e. the password of the user on the local server is different from the password of the user to the institution's storage. **If** the samba password would have been encrypted, though, the integrity of the institution would stay intact.

Comment: @BramVanroy not necessarily, the way you do Samba fstab mounts they'd just have to `mount` and have access to your storage, and can ransomware their way in, etc. that way.  Trust me, you probably need to implement some more security controls and follow best practices, the least of which is "don't give access where access isn't needed" to accounts.

Comment: In my final comment I meant that I could ask the institution providing the storage whether they would consider having two passwords per user: one for samba/storage access, and one for the rest of the systems. That should safeguard the sensitive information as well (that is not on the storage but in the admin part of the institution).

Comment: No, the storage is not what I am concerned with. The password also serves to access other information through an admin portal, completely unrelated to the storage. There, sensitive personal information is available.I understand what you are saying but in this case safeguarding the password *is* the important part. If the password cannot be retrieved, hackers can not get access to the sensitive information.

Comment: Another misunderstanding: what I mean with admin here is administrative information of employers, _not_ sudo access.

Comment: Concept of "least privilege" applies in all circumstances.  And administrative info of employees/employers is something that has to be handled as 'acceptable risk' alongside audits of credential use, etc.  and the reporting of potential "i think i've been hacked" situations.  All situations outside the scope of the question but not outside the scope of my 'best practices' arguments.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your best practices indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Cifscloak](https://github.com/sudoofus/cifscloak). You can install it using:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install cifscloak
```